# C# Checking if a class is X, OR inherited from X

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm fairly new to C# and I tried my best to find an already answered question similar to mine but I just could not get the answers to relate to my question.

So,
I have an "Instance"-class which is supposed to be a super class for all game objects.
It has a read-only ClassName property defined as such:

```
    public string ClassName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetType().Name;
        }
    }
```

And my reason for this question is that I want to have the following method which would return true if the current object is an instance of className, or if the object's class inherits from className.

```
    public bool IsA(string className)
    {
        //TODO
    }
```

This needs to be sort-of "recursive" so that if the case was:
**X : Class1 : Class2: Class4**
then X.IsA(Class4) would return true

I've looked into methods like object.GetType() but I haven't figured out a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: This needs to be sort-of "recursive" so that if the case was: X : Class1 : Class2: Class4 then X.IsA(Class4) would return true

Comment: Taken from the accepted answer in the duplicate thread: *`is` returns `true` if an instance is in the __inheritance tree__.* Relevant documentation: [is (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx).

Comment: Yes I just read that aswell but one problem still persists, my parameter is a string not a class

Comment: You're entering dangerous waters if you are using a string here. Are you sure that you are stuck using a string? If you show us where the string comes from, we may be able to suggest a cleaner alternative.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Elmuti/e09b066207eef0b551f0df6f56ce48f4 I wrote this based on that linked duplicate but I'm not sure if this will work

Comment: Just fixed that gist, but I am not sure if it works for my needs

Comment: I think the better question is why use a string to begin with?  Your ClassName property / IsA method serve no purpose except to duplicate language features already available, and you're not even using the full type name so your re-implementation can't differentiate between the same class name in two different namespaces.  If you need to print an object's type to the user / a log file, sure, go and get the name, but don't use the name programmatically, use the language features intended for solving exactly these problems.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `is` or `as` statement.
`as` will try to cast it to the target, and will be null if it fails (from memory).

Here's a quick linqpad demo (replace `"yep".Dump()"` with `Console.Out.Write("yep");` for VS):

```
void Main()
{
    var  b = new bar();

    if (b is foo)
        "yep".Dump();
    else
        "nope".Dump();

    var b2 = new bar();
    var b3 = b2 as foo;
    // you can check if b3 is null, or if not, use it a foo.

}


class foo {}

class bar : foo {}
```

Comment: You say to use `as` but then don't show it in use.

Comment: Does "b is foo" also check, for example if b is inherited from the class that foo inherits from?

Comment: @user3524922 what prevents you from checking the documentation for it first?

Comment: Well the problem is, the parameter is a string not a class

Comment: @user3524922 what do you mean the parameter is a string ?

Comment: @mason added, not really needed as `is` is probably what he wants. only he says it's strings ... so we'll see.